# Закончить ввод по нажатию F11 Си

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char* str;
    size_t buff = 300;
    size_t chars_s = getline(&str, &buff, stdin);
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
        if (str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9')
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    printf("Digit count: %d", count);
    return 0;
}
```

Нужно завершить работу этого кода по нажатию клавиши F11. Как это сделать?

Comment: Мне кажется, что это сделать нельзя.

Comment: Тогда надо считывать каждое нажатие, и самому либо добавлять символ в строку, либо завершать ввод...

Answer (score 0):

Есть вот такая реализация. Тут вы сможете посмотреть, узнать `hex` и `dec` код введенной клавиши. Однако, все же нет предположений как сделать через **F11**. Возможно тут дело в ноуте, но это так, бредовый аргумент. Если кто-то знает, то дополните этот код. P.S. В моем случае, выходит по нажатию **Tab** (0x9 по hex):

```
int key;
    do {
        while ((kbhit()) == 0);
        key = getch();
        if (key == 0x9) // Tab
            break;
        else { 
            printf("%c : %#X : %d\n", key, key, key); 
        }
    } while (true);
```

Comment: Дело в том, что нажатие ряда клавиш (всякие функциональные и т.п.) дают не один, а два кода. Надо смотреть на первый код, и в зависимости от него, читать второй...